# PHP Function not available on another page

Tags: php, function, session, include

I am trying to get a function to output on a page on my site.

All my functions are in `functions.php`, which I include in the head on all pages.

Here is an example function:

```
function get_username(){
    $userID = $_SESSION['user'];
    if($userID){
        $username = mysqli_query($dbconfig,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId='$userID'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($username)) {
            return $row['userName'];    
        }
    }
}
```

When calling the function `get_username` nothing is returned. To verify, I print the session to check the data exists, which it does.

I have also tried just echoing a simple word in the function like this:

```
function get_username(){
    echo 'test';
}
```

Again nothing is outputted. As mentioned above the functions.php is included in the head of the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: You also should look into variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/1415724 which is what @jeroen meant. Edit: Oh, you edited lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just added a link as well :-)

Comment: @jeroen I edited my comment about your edit lol

Comment: You generally shouldn't return inside a loop. That will end the loop, so you'll only return the value from the first row. You should collect all the results into an array, and return the array after the loop. If the query only returns 1 row, you don't need a loop in the first place.